# What are the pros and cons of these 2 example object designs

Tags: php, function, static

I have a general (PHP) design question which i keep spinning my head around. In this oversimplified example have an unverified object that i want to verify. In my limited knowledge i have to ways to-go.

Option 1) Either using a static function as - let's say - a verifier. Here i separated concerns(?). The object itself is not responsible for handling the verification. We use a service object(?) that takes care of that.

```
<?php

class Verifier {
    public static function verify(UnverifiedThing $unverifiedThing) : VerifiedThing {
        return new VerifiedThing($unverifiedThing);
    }
}
```

Option 2) Or instead using a function inside unverified class, where this object itself is responsible for the actual verification and returns a new verified object.

```
class UnverifiedThing {
    public function verify() : VerifiedThing {
        return new VerifiedThing($this);
    }
}
```

What would be the pros/cons over each other? Or are there even better designs which i did not consider?

Comment: Letting unverified things verify themselves is like letting the fox run the hen house, isn't it?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for CodeReview.stackexchange.com than StackOverflow.

Comment: @Barmar aah. did not knew that existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To me, personally, Option 2 does not appear intuitive. An object morphing itself by creating a second object? No way.

Option 1 is the usual approach, although typically one does not use static functions. Have a try designing a verification authority object that is able to verify a given object. That binds run time settings to that object instead of keeping them global and allow for separate types of such agents. Also such agents are easier to use in automatic test cases, since you can easily mock them.

Comment: Thanks.. I might have chosen the wrong words now what i think about it. It's not actually a verifier, but more a 'converter'. The object can't be instantiated if its not valid in the first case.

Comment: Does not change that much, actually. Only you do not want to create a second, validated object then, but only mark the existing object as "verified". This can be done internally by a self verification method or just as a proposed above: by a verification agent.

Comment: can you eleborate a  bit more about why it's better to not have a static method? I am using it because..

Comment: i use a static function cause

1) i am not trying to build verifiers, its a utility class
2) i am not using any instance vars and its not depending on instance vars
3) this function would not change in the future

i might be very wrong, just wondering.

Comment: Well, I think I _did_ give two clear reasons in the answer, why static methods typically should be avoided. How do you want to write test for the verification logic when using a static method? They are a fall back into procedural programming style. Why would one want to do that?

Comment: There is not really a verification logic in the verifier -that is why i think i choose the wrong words-, its just converting to a new object, and that new object can't be instantiated if its not verified. The logic is all encapsulated in the  object itself. A verified object can't be NOT verified (for example, it needs to have some valid types, otherwise it can't be instantiated). In your example by marking an object as 'verified' there is actual state changing in the object. The same object could either be verified, or not be verified...

Comment: So.. in your example of marking an object verified or not verified i need to do this..

    doSomthing(object) {i have 
}

Comment: Sorry, but this goes in circles now. Maybe I miss the point. Sorry for that.

Comment: So.. in your example of marking an object verified or not verified i need to do this..

    doSomthing(object) {
        // i have no idea if this object is verified or not, i need to check it all over the place
    }


in my example

    doSomething(VerifiedObject $object) {
        // i know the object is verified, no need to check
    }

Comment: Sorry, can't follow here. Obviously it is a difference if your can safely assume that an object is verified or if can not. But that all has no bearing on the question if that verify method or function you suggested should be designed as a static method, so more or less a global procedure, or as the method of an active agent. you did not react at all to my reasons but apparently shift the goal of what you are asking.

Comment: you are right, i am shifting it now and take to many concepts into consideration. Thank you for taking some time. 

As a sidenote, these 2 screenshos might explain a bit more what i am thinking about. Thank you for your time.

[one](https://postimg.org/image/jbin8ajyt/) 
[two](https://postimg.org/image/fdvdivx5h/)

Comment: No, sorry, they do not shed additional light on your situation... A general note: please always add additional information to the question itself, not into comments buried deep in the page. There is an `edit` link below it. _Use it_. :-)